# Security Issue with Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

The retard who was on the built-in Administrator login somehow (and this is what I'm guessing being as he is not here and I was not present when this occurred - Supposedly it was an "ACCIDENT") Denied the built-in Administrator account and every other account except for his personal one access to our domain - ie "Example.net" not just active directory or anything.

I've been trying for literally 2 hours to find some sort of way to take control of the domain through the built-in Admin account with no success; I can't even open Active Directory. I'm not aloud to open DSA.MSC and there's no way for me to take ownership.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a backup of AD?

Comment: How does one remove all rights assigned to the domain administrator account from a non-AD-controller PC? I'm guessing AD doesn't have some sort of protection built in for having at least one administrative user?

Answer (score 1):

These [instructions](http://www.petri.co.il/reset_domain_admin_password_in_windows_server_2003_ad.htm) should help you reset the local administrator, then the domain administrator.  You will of course need physical console access to a Domain Controller.

Comment: I think he has the password, the problem is the built in admin account has had its permissions removed.

Comment: He could use the same technique to reset the privileged users password.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'd know of is to restore from backup, but that introduces another problem also if you're following the best practices of multiple controllers. AD controllers don't like having one system "rolled back" as it can massively fubar the AD structure.

The second thing...heck...I'd probably have to call an MSCE consultant to fix that issue if you don't have any users with delegated administrative privileges or belonging to and administrative group. They usually have access to Microsoft's support numbers to get through the maze and cut through some of the tape to find the answer if they didn't already know, and if your directory and server structure is valuable for your business...i.e., reconstruction from scratch will take too much time...the cost will be worth it.

I'd love to hear the solution here if/when you find one.

Comment: Authoritative restores are surprisingly not too painful.  The major problem is going to be lost changes.  Edit: just realized this was an old question...

Comment: MCSEs don't get free support calls. Certified Partners (at least at Gold level) get a few free calls. But, a support call is only $125, last I knew. Often very worth it, and probably in this case.